# When is "Have you known" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

We usually say:

> **Did** you **know** that penguins can't fly, although they are classified as "birds"?

But, when "Have you known" is grammactly correct?

Comment: Have you known anyone to answer such a question in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How long have you known that penguins can't fly?"

The present perfect tense draws attention to the circumstance after the action is complete.  The interrogative "how long"  sounds natural with a present perfect.